# Open Source Metadata Management Tool

Tags: metadata, data-warehouse

I'm not sure "Metadata Management" is the right term....

Basically, I have a client who asked for recommendations on "Metadata Management" tools with regard to a data warehousing project they have.  I'm guessing the term has to do with creating something like a data dictionary, but I have relatively little experience in this area and am asking from a point of ignorance.

I've been told (but have not seen firsthand) that the client is currently using Excel as their current tool for "Metadata Management", but would like something slightly more robust.

If anyone can shed some light on this term and possibly some open source solutions, I'd appreciate it.

I was going to suggest a free wiki like MoinMoin so that they could create a "web" of terms, but I'm not sure if this is the right path.

Comment: Whats databases are you running.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [CA Erwin Community Edition](http://www.ca.com/us/products/product.aspx?id=8242)?